# String to Date parsing in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a data string 'yyyymmddhhmmss' example: '20101001151014', how Do I parse this to date in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime when = DateTime.ParseExact("20101001151014", "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Points to note: 24-hour  hour is HH; 2-digit month is MM

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateTime.ParseExact method.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ParseExact`  you can use and parse it

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20101001151014", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime ShortDateStringToDate(string dateText)
{
    if (dateText == null)
        return DateTime.MinValue;

    if (dateText.Length != 14)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    string dateFormatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```