# Selection between two date pickers

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

This is the code that I wrote in order to make a selection between two dates (using `DateTimePicker` objects)

```
var query = db.people.AsQueryable();

var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1);
var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2);

query = query.Where(x => x.dob > fromDate && x.dob < toDate);
clan_savezaBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

When I run the code the error appears saying `InvalidCastException`. I guess I should use something other than `Convert.ToDate` but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836688/string-to-date-parsing-in-c) maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Value` property of `DateTimePicker`. It returns selected the date as `DateTime` object:

```
var fromDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
var toDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

Note: `DateTimePicker` is not a `DateTime` object. And it's not convertible to `DateTime`. `DateTimePicker` is a user control which holds `DateTime` value and provides a lot of functionality for rendering itself and processing user input.

Further reading: [Using DateTimePicker Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231249(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Sergey, thank you so much for this explanation. Solved, it works. Thanks again!